# RPI3: static IP address usable when moving - not sure if possible

Tags: static-ip

I'd like my RPI to have a static ip address since I'll need to move it between locations (including other countries).

So ideally, whenever it connects to a network, either through LAN or WiFi, it will always have the same IP.

I'm not sure if it is possible though. Any advice?

Comment: Set the static IP from router(s) then, not from your RPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer you question, Yes it would be possible but not without difficulties.

The static address you assign the PI would need to be outside of the DHCP range or reserved on each of the networks it's going to be joining. If it's already in use or handed out by a DHCP server you will cause an address conflict when your PI shows up.

You're almost certainly going run into problems with different IP address ranges and subnets too.

Comment: This is does not provide an answer.

Comment: It does in the sense that it explains it is not literally impossible, but at the same time, very very unrealistic.